# Load unsafe script error: http vs https

Tags: arcgis-server, amazon-web-services

We have an ArcGIS server hosted on Amazon. The maps and layers on that server are used to build a website (i.e. xxxx.com/map. The problem is, that page always shows an error "load unsafe scritps". If anyone allows to load those scripts then the webpage works fine with all the contents. I have inspected the page source in google chrome and it shows error/warnings such as

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx.com/map/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FinalMaps/MapServer/export?bbox=-8588464.498122405%2C5106604.985676053%2C-7998370.639760844%2C4564819.329190728&size=965%2C886&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&layers=show%3A46&f=json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there anyway so that the hosted layer on ArcGIS server can be accessed through a https link instead of http